# how can i get to know the frequency of a speech signal?

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis

What is the **actual meaning of frequency**? what if the signal is aperiodic??
In general, we say that frequency means the repeatition of an event in unit time. But what about a speech signal? how can we say that a speech signal is having 4KHz Bandwidth(say)?

Comment: Nearly 2 centuries ago, Fourier showed almost any reasonable bounded signal, even aperiodic, could be represented by a bunch of sinusoids of various frequencies.  Each sinusoid repeats.

Comment: To expand on the above, any complex signal can be considered to be the sum of many simple sinusoids, each with its own frequency, phase and amplitude.  The bandwidth is then the total range of frequencies needed to represent the signal.  So a 4kHz bandwidth implies that the signal can be represented as a series of sinusoids, where the difference between the highest and the lowest frequency is 4kHz.

Answer (score 1):

A speech signal can contain a lot more than 4kHz bandwidth, however experiments showed that if you removed all but the spectrum below 3kHz (thus allowing the use of cheaper circuitry), it was still reasonably understandable by another human.

Comment: that is a different thing But how can i say that the speech signal has a frequency of 4 kHz?

Comment: You can't really say that the speech signal has a frequency of 4kHz.  A speech signal may well contain components that include 4kHz.  Have you ever looked at the spectrogram of a speech signal.  If not, have a look here: http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/pnl/demo/IBM.html  The diagrams labeled "Spectrogram of clean speech" show what normal speech looks like.  Notice that there are often high intensities around 4kHz (yellow and red,) but there is not a single frequency that dominates.  Note also that although there are components above kHz, the most intense components are below around 3kHz.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that the only thing that has a frequency of 4 kHz is a 4 kHz sine wave. We don't say that a speech signal has a particular frequency. Instead, we say that the energy of the speech signal is spread over various frequencies. We use the Fourier transform to decompose the energy of a speech signal across various frequencies. This is visualized by way of the [spectrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram).